# ¿Cómo es un diagrama de clases del patrón arquitectónico MVC tomando en cuenta las relaciones de asociación?

Tags: java, patrones-de-diseño, arquitectura-de-software

Es que he visto diagramas de clases del patrón MVC (Model-View-Controller), pero en los mismos no especifican si las asociaciones son de composición o agregación. Esto es de importancia porque al momento de implementar el código puedo saber cuáles objetos dependen de cuáles, es decir dónde y cómo se producen los cruzamientos de objetos.

Imagen del diagrama, pero sin las especificaciones que mencioné, es solo a manera de ejemplo. Igualmente ignorar la clase observer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me ayudan por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien las implementacones de MVC varían según la plataforma donde se implementen (no es lo mismo implementarlo en javafx que en una web application con servlets), en tu diagrama tenés a modo de propiedades cuales referencias tiene cada clase de las otras.

Con eso y los métodos que están también en el diagrama me parece que es suficiente para darte una idea de como programarlo.

Para darte un ejemplo, la clase `View` tiene como atributos `myModel` y `myController`, entonces,  `View` mantiene una referencia tanto a `Model` como a `Controller`. Y así con las otras clases.

Y si mas o menos entendés como es el flujo en MVC, con el nombre de los métodos podés hasta intuir donde se deberia usar cada uno.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Juan, es cierto. Por último los métodos donde dice initialize(x) se refiere a los set verdad? Por ejemplo, initializeModel(Modelo modelo) sería lo mismo que setModel(Modelo model). Lo pregunto porque no sé si en el diagrama se refiere al constructor. ¿Y donde dice makeController() se refiere a instanciar?

Comment: Me parece que ese método que se llama sobre el Controller es para inicializarlo con la vista y el modelo. Osea en algún lado se crea una instancia de la vista, una instancia del modelo, y una instancia del controlador, y con este método le decis al controlador que vista y que modelo debe usar (y setear internamente a sus atributos)